# camelCase ctrl left and right for titanium studio?

Tags: titanium

so i'm using titanium studio, and i've noticed that it, like jetBrains, comes pre-packaged with the idea that ctrl-left or ctrl-right on a word goes to the beginning or end of that word, and not to the "camel cased" sub-part.

Ugh, here, an example:

```
|ThisIsCool = new ArrayList();
```

Assuming that the "pipe" character is the cursor, if i hit ctrl-right once, i'd like it to go to:

```
This|IsCool = new ArrayList();
```

And again:

```
ThisIs|Cool = new ArrayList();
```

instead, in Titanium studio it just jumps to the `=` sign.

How do i get Titanium studio to behave right? I assume it is a setting of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key bindings are located in Window->Perferences->Keys.

I experimented with some of the options, but Next Word was the closest I could find that would maybe accomplish what you wanted.  When I bound that, it just did exactly what the default CTRL+Right Arrow was already doing.  There is no 'camel' or 'cap' (for capital letter).  It doesn't appear to me that this function is built into the IDE.  If you look at that section, perhaps something in there will catch your eye and get that working for you.

Otherwise, I would probably hit up the Appcelerator specific forums and perhaps get a developer there to notice it.

Comment: yeah you're right "impossible" is the answer - thanks for trying though!